# How to split a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df which looks like this:

```
df.head()
Close
Date    
2011-12-31  4.472624
2012-01-01  4.680778
2012-01-02  5.000000
2012-01-03  5.145917
2012-01-04  5.228729
```

and I wanna split the data into two parts according this attempt:

```
# Split data
df_train = df['2017':'2020-04'].iloc[:, 0:1].values #an array of Close values
df_test = df['2020-04':].iloc[:, 0:1].values #an array of Close values
```

... which raises:

> KeyError: '2017'

The year is included in the dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `'2017'` is no valid index, thus you get a `KeyError`. Are your dates strings or datetime objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your index to datetime

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd    
df.index = df.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')    
df_train = df[(df.index > '2017-01-01') & (df.index < '2020-04-01')]
df_test = df[df.index > '2020-04-01']
```

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Comment: Is CloseDate an index or just normal column?

Comment: Try the answer above.